# Nextflow in cmd process is expanded

Tags: nextflow

I just created a new environment for nextflow, but when I run the script, the process steps are expanded like this:

```
[warm up] executor > local
[9c/f50613] Submitted process > bowtie2_target_genome (2)
[1f/1b1f43] Submitted process > bowtie2_vector (1)
[d0/4b99a5] Submitted process > bowtie2_vector (3)
[ef/183556] Submitted process > bowtie2_target_genome (1)
[4a/330246] Submitted process > bowtie2_target_genome (4)
[0b/1e00ff] Submitted process > bowtie2_vector (4)
[bd/ad292b] Submitted process > bowtie2_vector (2)
[98/1caa92] Submitted process > bowtie2_vector (5)
[55/2f25bb] Submitted process > bowtie2_target_genome (5)
[05/5890e2] Submitted process > bowtie2_target_genome (3)
```

It used to be look like this:

```
executor >  local (1)
[14/0418b6] process > bowtie2_target_genome (3)      [100%] 5 of 5
[a3/7b824b] process > bowtie2_vector (1)             [100%] 5 of 5
[fc/1b8883] process > aln_sum (5)                    [100%] 5 of 5
[57/0762c0] process > create_bedgraph_and_bigwig (2) [100%] 5 of 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've added `-ansi-log false` to your run command. The default value for this option is 'true', so either use that or remove the option altogether.

Setting `-ansi-log false` is helpful when running Nextflow in a non-interactive shell. Your command-line might look like:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf
```